# How to personalize account view in Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, spree

I'm actually developing on Spree ECommerce solution, and I would like to personalize the "**account**" view ( 127.0.0.1:3000/account ), but **I can't find it** in the **/core** of Spree.

I'm also searching for the **spree_auth_devise** Gem to personalize it, but I can't understand how it work.

Cannot find the right way in the documentation of spree.

If someone has a clue, i'm open (:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by overriding the `app/views/spree/users/show.html.erb` template by putting a template at the same path within your application.

Comment: Note that `show.html.erb` is actually part of the `spree_auth_devise` gem (not `spree`) and the latest can be seen here: https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise/blob/master/lib/views/frontend/spree/users/show.html.erb